# Ruby PDF generation with CombinePDF & StringIO removes "<" character

Tags: ruby, pdf, special-characters, stringio, combine-pdf

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make < show up in pdf generation using CombinePDF & StringIO. > shows up fine in the generated pdf but not <. I can't easily change the software I'm using and would ideally escape "<" so that it still shows up in the pdf. I would post the code here but it's extensive across multiple files.

Anyone have an idea what I can try to get the symbol to show up in my pdf? Is there a way to choose an encoding type in CombinePDF or StringIO on ruby on rails.

Thank you in advance, sorry for a more broad question. I've been working on this for a day now and need any help you can provide.

Comment: do you have some code sample?

Comment: You explicitly mention `StringIO` - does it only affect the PDF when using a `StringIO`? Or also when you are using a plain old `File`?

The `StringIO` object should use the binary encoding since a PDF is nearly always in binary format (for example, initialize the `StringIO` with `StringIO.new(''.b)`.